# SQL while loop to merge by relationship link until no more can be linked

Tags: sql, while-loop

In SQL, i have a table that looks like this

| Person | Related Parent |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| C | NULL |
| D | B |
| E | NULL |

How could i write a while loop in SQL so this table merge itself until each person is found with the "Ultimate End Related Parent".

I tried a do while loop to start with declaring the 1st merge result to be varchar() and WHILE the declared variiable remains null, keep merging.

I am fairly new to SQL especially writing loops.  Any help would be great

So the results will look like this

Result:

| Person | Ultimate Related Parent |
| --- | --- |
| A | C |
| B | C |
| C | NULL |
| D | C |
| E | NULL |

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server? Also, what have you tried so far, where did you get stuck? This community expects you to show some research effort.